# Pandas Dataframe: Split mixed float-string column into separate float and string columns

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe column named 'VALUE' which has string data like this: '-1.459NS'
I want to create 2 new columns -> 'VALUE' must have a float -1.459 and UNIT must have a string 'NS'

Is there a Regex and/or Non Regex way of doing this? 
What is the fastest way of doing this? I have maybe a million + lines over which I want to do this.

```
>>> d = {'VALUE': ['-1.234NS','0.22MH']}
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
      VALUE
0  -1.234NS
1    0.22MH
```

I want:

```
    VALUE    UNIT
0  -1.234    NS
1    0.22    MH
```

Where VALUE is float and UNIT is string

Comment: Are units always 2-characters long?

Comment: The units can be any number of characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df.column.str.extract` will produce a dataframe with one column per matched group in the regex, indexed by int position. Then you can use `rename` to rename the columns.

```
>>> df.VALUE.str.extract(r'([-]?[\d.]*)([\w\D]*)').rename(columns={0:'VALUE', 1:'UNIT'})

    VALUE UNIT
0  -1.234   NS
1    0.22   MH
```

Comment: My approach would have been `df.VALUE.str.extract('([+-.0-9]+)(.*)')`, then plus sign is allowed and UNIT could have numbers, too - however, I'm not a regex expert, but at least for the sample above it would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another non-regex way to solve this if the following units aren't fixed lengths. This will split the string into float numbers and string type units.

```
s = '-1.234NS'
a,b = map(str, s.split("."))
a = a + '.'
unit = ''
for num in b:
    try:
        float(num)
        a += num
    except ValueError:
        unit += num
fl = float(a)
```